Export panda dataframe after grouping data groupby() into google spreadsheet in google colaboratory
I use google colaboratory to do data grouping for a very large data (180 k row, 40 columns). I manage to do the grouping like below
df_1 = df.groupby(['CABANG','JENIS_PELAYARAN',pd.cut(df['GRT'], [0, 3500, 8000, 14000, 18000, 26000, 40000, 75000, 300000])])['PENDAPATAN_TUNDA'].sum().reset_index(name="sum")

But when I want to export, I was failed. Below is my script
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
spreadsheet = gc.open_by_key('1a1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
target = spreadsheet.get_worksheet_by_id(1174387715)
target.update(None,df_1)

Here is the error message
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-53-e8e474ea1e57> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 
      3 target = spreadsheet.get_worksheet_by_id(1174387715)
----> 4 target.update(None,df_1)

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1517     @final
   1518     def __nonzero__(self) -> NoReturn:
-> 1519         raise ValueError(
   1520             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1521             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().



Is there any steps that I was missing? I have followed other similar topic here but it is different with my question here.
The original dataframe head as dictionary is as below
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'No': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'WLAYAH': {1: 'Wil 3',
  2: 'Wil 3',
  3: 'Wil 3',
  4: 'Wil 3',
  5: 'Wil 3',
  6: 'Wil 3',
  7: 'Wil 3',
  8: 'Wil 3',
  9: 'Wil 3',
  10: 'Wil 3',
  11: 'Wil 3',
  12: 'Wil 3',
  13: 'Wil 3',
  14: 'Wil 3',
  15: 'Wil 3',
  16: 'Wil 3',
  17: 'Wil 3',
  18: 'Wil 3',
  19: 'Wil 3',
  20: 'Wil 3',
  21: 'Wil 3',
  22: 'Wil 3',
  23: 'Wil 3',
  24: 'Wil 3',
  25: 'Wil 3',
  26: 'Wil 3',
  27: 'Wil 3',
  28: 'Wil 3',
  29: 'Wil 3',
  30: 'Wil 3'},
 'CABANG': {1: 'BMASIN',
  2: 'BMASIN',
  3: 'BMASIN',
  4: 'BMASIN',
  5: 'BMASIN',
  6: 'BMASIN',
  7: 'BMASIN',
  8: 'BMASIN',
  9: 'BMASIN',
  10: 'BMASIN',
  11: 'BMASIN',
  12: 'BMASIN',
  13: 'BMASIN',
  14: 'BMASIN',
  15: 'BMASIN',
  16: 'BMASIN',
  17: 'BMASIN',
  18: 'BMASIN',
  19: 'BMASIN',
  20: 'BMASIN',
  21: 'BMASIN',
  22: 'BMASIN',
  23: 'BMASIN',
  24: 'BMASIN',
  25: 'BMASIN',
  26: 'BMASIN',
  27: 'BMASIN',
  28: 'BMASIN',
  29: 'BMASIN',
  30: 'BMASIN'},
 'NAMA_KAPAL': {1: 'ISM 3024',
  2: 'ISM 3024',
  3: 'ISM 3024',
  4: 'ISM 3024',
  5: 'ISM 3024',
  6: 'ISM 3024',
  7: 'ISM 3024',
  8: 'ISM 3024',
  9: 'ISM 3024',
  10: 'ISM 3024',
  11: 'ISM 3024',
  12: 'ISM 3024',
  13: 'ISM 3024',
  14: 'ISM 3024',
  15: 'ISM 3024',
  16: 'ISM 3024',
  17: 'ISM 3024',
  18: 'ISM 3024',
  19: 'ISM 3024',
  20: 'ISM 3024',
  21: 'ISM 3024',
  22: 'ISM 3024',
  23: 'ISM 3024',
  24: 'ISM 3024',
  25: 'ISM 3024',
  26: 'ISM 3024',
  27: 'ISM 3024',
  28: 'ISM 3024',
  29: 'ISM 3024',
  30: 'ISM 3024'},
 'JENIS_KAPAL': {1: 'TONG',
  2: 'TONG',
  3: 'TONG',
  4: 'TONG',
  5: 'TONG',
  6: 'TONG',
  7: 'TONG',
  8: 'TONG',
  9: 'TONG',
  10: 'TONG',
  11: 'TONG',
  12: 'TONG',
  13: 'TONG',
  14: 'TONG',
  15: 'TONG',
  16: 'TONG',
  17: 'TONG',
  18: 'TONG',
  19: 'TONG',
  20: 'TONG',
  21: 'TONG',
  22: 'TONG',
  23: 'TONG',
  24: 'TONG',
  25: 'TONG',
  26: 'TONG',
  27: 'TONG',
  28: 'TONG',
  29: 'TONG',
  30: 'TONG'},
 'JENIS_PELAYARAN': {1: 'DNEGERI',
  2: 'DNEGERI',
  3: 'DNEGERI',
  4: 'DNEGERI',
  5: 'DNEGERI',
  6: 'DNEGERI',
  7: 'DNEGERI',
  8: 'DNEGERI',
  9: 'DNEGERI',
  10: 'DNEGERI',
  11: 'DNEGERI',
  12: 'DNEGERI',
  13: 'DNEGERI',
  14: 'DNEGERI',
  15: 'DNEGERI',
  16: 'DNEGERI',
  17: 'DNEGERI',
  18: 'DNEGERI',
  19: 'DNEGERI',
  20: 'DNEGERI',
  21: 'DNEGERI',
  22: 'DNEGERI',
  23: 'DNEGERI',
  24: 'DNEGERI',
  25: 'DNEGERI',
  26: 'DNEGERI',
  27: 'DNEGERI',
  28: 'DNEGERI',
  29: 'DNEGERI',
  30: 'DNEGERI'},
 'GRT': {1: '3420',
  2: '3420',
  3: '3420',
  4: '3106',
  5: '3106',
  6: '3106',
  7: '7251',
  8: '7251',
  9: '7251',
  10: '3107',
  11: '3107',
  12: '3107',
  13: '7487',
  14: '7487',
  15: '7487',
  16: '3117',
  17: '3117',
  18: '3117',
  19: '5241',
  20: '5241',
  21: '5241',
  22: '2415',
  23: '2415',
  24: '2415',
  25: '5338',
  26: '5338',
  27: '5338',
  28: '5309',
  29: '5309',
  30: '5309'},
 'LOA': {1: '91.44',
  2: '91.44',
  3: '91.44',
  4: '87.74',
  5: '87.74',
  6: '87.74',
  7: '120',
  8: '120',
  9: '120',
  10: '91.44',
  11: '91.44',
  12: '91.44',
  13: '118',
  14: '118',
  15: '118',
  16: '91.44',
  17: '91.44',
  18: '91.44',
  19: '111.25',
  20: '111.25',
  21: '111.25',
  22: '82.3',
  23: '82.3',
  24: '82.3',
  25: '111.25',
  26: '111.25',
  27: '111.25',
  28: '106.68',
  29: '106.68',
  30: '106.68'},
 'NAMA_AGEN': {1: 'SINAR BINTANG DUTA MULIA, PT',
  2: 'SINAR BINTANG DUTA MULIA, PT',
  3: 'SINAR BINTANG DUTA MULIA, PT',
  4: 'SARANA MARITIM SEJAHTERA PT',
  5: 'SARANA MARITIM SEJAHTERA PT',
  6: 'SARANA MARITIM SEJAHTERA PT',
  7: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  8: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  9: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  10: 'SARANA MARITIM SEJAHTERA PT',
  11: 'SARANA MARITIM SEJAHTERA PT',
  12: 'SARANA MARITIM SEJAHTERA PT',
  13: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  14: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  15: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  16: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  17: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  18: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  19: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  20: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  21: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  22: 'BARITO SAMUDRA SEJAHTERA, PT',
  23: 'BARITO SAMUDRA SEJAHTERA, PT',
  24: 'BARITO SAMUDRA SEJAHTERA, PT',
  25: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  26: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  27: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  28: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  29: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT',
  30: 'TERA LOGISTIC INDONESIA, PT'},
 'SPK_PILOT': {1: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  2: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  3: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  4: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  5: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  6: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  7: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  8: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  9: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  10: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  11: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  12: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  13: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  14: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  15: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  16: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  17: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  18: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  19: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  20: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  21: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  22: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  23: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  24: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  25: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  26: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  27: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  28: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  29: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231',
  30: 'IDBDJ-SPK.231'},
 'NAMA_PANDU': {1: 'EDWINANDRA',
  2: 'SUGITTMOKO',
  3: 'SAMUERANNU',
  4: 'DODIKSMAIL',
  5: 'HABIBAJANY',
  6: 'IRWAN JAYA',
  7: 'DHANINSYAH',
  8: 'RUDY  BUDY',
  9: 'FIRMAFULAH',
  10: 'FIRMAFULAH',
  11: 'AKHADAMMAD',
  12: 'RIGELPILOR',
  13: 'IRWAN JAYA',
  14: 'RAHMAHMADI',
  15: 'TRIONIANTO',
  16: 'CANDRDIMAN',
  17: 'KUSNASNADI',
  18: 'SULISIANTO',
  19: 'RAHMAHMADI',
  20: 'FISARHTIAR',
  21: 'SUMBOMBONO',
  22: 'SAMUERANNU',
  23: 'RUDY  BUDY',
  24: 'EKO WNARTO',
  25: 'EKO HYANTO',
  26: 'SAMUERANNU',
  27: 'SUGITTMOKO',
  28: 'SYAMSAMSUL',
  29: 'ANGGAIJAYA',
  30: 'SUMBOMBONO'},
 'PANDU_DARI': {1: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  2: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  3: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  4: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  5: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  6: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  7: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  8: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  9: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  10: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  11: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  12: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  13: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  14: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  15: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  16: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  17: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  18: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  19: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  20: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  21: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  22: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  23: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  24: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  25: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  26: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  27: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  28: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  29: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  30: 'PULAU BAKUT'},
 'TUG_1': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'TUG_2': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'TUG_3': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'TUG_4': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'TUG1_REALISASI': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'TUG2_REALISASI': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'TUG3_REALISASI': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'TUG4_REALISASI': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'USAGE_TUG1': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'USAGE_TUG2': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'USAGE_TUG3': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'USAGE_TUG4': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'FS_TIME_TUG1': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'FS_TIME_TUG2': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'FS_TIME_TUG3': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'FS_TIME_TUG4': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'FS_FUEL_USAGE_TUG1': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'FS_FUEL_USAGE_TUG2': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'FS_FUEL_USAGE_TUG3': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'FS_FUEL_USAGE_TUG4': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'JProduksi': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'ProdVar': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'Gol': {1: 'BMASIN1',
  2: 'BMASIN1',
  3: 'BMASIN1',
  4: 'BMASIN1',
  5: 'BMASIN1',
  6: 'BMASIN1',
  7: 'BMASIN2',
  8: 'BMASIN2',
  9: 'BMASIN2',
  10: 'BMASIN1',
  11: 'BMASIN1',
  12: 'BMASIN1',
  13: 'BMASIN2',
  14: 'BMASIN2',
  15: 'BMASIN2',
  16: 'BMASIN1',
  17: 'BMASIN1',
  18: 'BMASIN1',
  19: 'BMASIN2',
  20: 'BMASIN2',
  21: 'BMASIN2',
  22: 'BMASIN1',
  23: 'BMASIN1',
  24: 'BMASIN1',
  25: 'BMASIN2',
  26: 'BMASIN2',
  27: 'BMASIN2',
  28: 'BMASIN2',
  29: 'BMASIN2',
  30: 'BMASIN2'},
 'FixT': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'VarT': {1: '',
  2: '',
  3: '',
  4: '',
  5: '',
  6: '',
  7: '',
  8: '',
  9: '',
  10: '',
  11: '',
  12: '',
  13: '',
  14: '',
  15: '',
  16: '',
  17: '',
  18: '',
  19: '',
  20: '',
  21: '',
  22: '',
  23: '',
  24: '',
  25: '',
  26: '',
  27: '',
  28: '',
  29: '',
  30: ''},
 'PANDU_KE': {1: 'LAUT',
  2: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  3: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  4: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  5: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  6: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  7: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  8: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  9: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  10: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  11: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  12: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  13: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  14: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  15: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  16: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  17: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  18: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  19: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  20: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  21: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  22: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  23: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  24: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  25: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  26: 'REDE TRISAKTI',
  27: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  28: 'AMBANG LUAR',
  29: 'PULAU BAKUT',
  30: 'REDE TRISAKTI'},
 'TIPE_LOKASI': {1: 'UMUM',
  2: 'UMUM',
  3: 'UMUM',
  4: 'UMUM',
  5: 'UMUM',
  6: 'UMUM',
  7: 'UMUM',
  8: 'UMUM',
  9: 'UMUM',
  10: 'UMUM',
  11: 'UMUM',
  12: 'UMUM',
  13: 'UMUM',
  14: 'UMUM',
  15: 'UMUM',
  16: 'UMUM',
  17: 'UMUM',
  18: 'UMUM',
  19: 'UMUM',
  20: 'UMUM',
  21: 'UMUM',
  22: 'UMUM',
  23: 'UMUM',
  24: 'UMUM',
  25: 'UMUM',
  26: 'UMUM',
  27: 'UMUM',
  28: 'UMUM',
  29: 'UMUM',
  30: 'UMUM'},
 'TIPE_GERAKAN': {1: 'KELUAR',
  2: 'PINDAH',
  3: 'MASUK',
  4: 'PINDAH',
  5: 'MASUK',
  6: 'KELUAR',
  7: 'KELUAR',
  8: 'PINDAH',
  9: 'MASUK',
  10: 'PINDAH',
  11: 'KELUAR',
  12: 'MASUK',
  13: 'PINDAH',
  14: 'KELUAR',
  15: 'MASUK',
  16: 'MASUK',
  17: 'KELUAR',
  18: 'PINDAH',
  19: 'KELUAR',
  20: 'PINDAH',
  21: 'MASUK',
  22: 'MASUK',
  23: 'PINDAH',
  24: 'KELUAR',
  25: 'KELUAR',
  26: 'MASUK',
  27: 'PINDAH',
  28: 'PINDAH',
  29: 'KELUAR',
  30: 'MASUK'},
 'PENDAPATAN_PANDU': {1: '512166',
  2: '384125',
  3: '512166',
  4: '369887',
  5: '493182',
  6: '493182',
  7: '730734',
  8: '548051',
  9: '730734',
  10: '370811',
  11: '494414',
  12: '494414',
  13: '557795',
  14: '743726',
  15: '743726',
  16: '491670',
  17: '491670',
  18: '368753',
  19: '615990',
  20: '461993',
  21: '615990',
  22: '451294',
  23: '338471',
  24: '451294',
  25: '619966',
  26: '619966',
  27: '464975',
  28: '464933',
  29: '619910',
  30: '619910'},
 'PENDAPATAN_TUNDA': {1: '0',
  2: '0',
  3: '0',
  4: '0',
  5: '0',
  6: '0',
  7: '0',
  8: '0',
  9: '0',
  10: '0',
  11: '0',
  12: '0',
  13: '0',
  14: '0',
  15: '0',
  16: '0',
  17: '0',
  18: '0',
  19: '0',
  20: '0',
  21: '0',
  22: '0',
  23: '0',
  24: '0',
  25: '0',
  26: '0',
  27: '0',
  28: '0',
  29: '0',
  30: '0'},
 'PENDAPATAN_FS': {1: '0',
  2: '0',
  3: '0',
  4: '0',
  5: '0',
  6: '0',
  7: '0',
  8: '0',
  9: '0',
  10: '0',
  11: '0',
  12: '0',
  13: '0',
  14: '0',
  15: '0',
  16: '0',
  17: '0',
  18: '0',
  19: '0',
  20: '0',
  21: '0',
  22: '0',
  23: '0',
  24: '0',
  25: '0',
  26: '0',
  27: '0',
  28: '0',
  29: '0',
  30: '0'},
 'PENDAPATAN_TOTAL': {1: '512166',
  2: '384125',
  3: '512166',
  4: '369887',
  5: '493182',
  6: '493182',
  7: '730734',
  8: '548051',
  9: '730734',
  10: '370811',
  11: '494414',
  12: '494414',
  13: '557795',
  14: '743726',
  15: '743726',
  16: '491670',
  17: '491670',
  18: '368753',
  19: '615990',
  20: '461993',
  21: '615990',
  22: '451294',
  23: '338471',
  24: '451294',
  25: '619966',
  26: '619966',
  27: '464975',
  28: '464933',
  29: '619910',
  30: '619910'}})


The error doesn't look related to exporting the data, but rather to filtering and grouping the original dataframe. Can you share the original dataframe head, as a dictionary?

Hi! Thanks for the reply. Could you guide how to find and share original dataframe head? Sorry I'm still new to google colaboratory

This is not about google colab, this is about pandas. See the documentation here on how to export pandas to JSON. Or like this, to_dict.

Also, how are you new to google colab, when you asked a question about colab and pandas three years ago?

Hi! Yes three years ago I started studying Colab and Panda. Shortly afterwards, my projects had been stopped by my office so I left Colab and Panda. Now I open again the project and resume the process. Thanks for the reference, kindly wait a moment for me to find a way to use to_dict feature.

Here what I found. I read from other topic. I use df.head(1).to_dict() it gives output without any error. I have shared the output on the original question above.

You need to share at least the first 100 rows from that df mate, so it can be grouped accordingly.

Could I share the 100 rows from 4 columns only related to my filtering attempt? Pardon me because the data is very sensitive related to our customer.

Then change the names & figures and share it like that

I have updated the original question above and add original dataframe head as dictionary for 100 rows. Thank you for waiting.

You did not post a copy pasteable dict, so someone can reproduce your issue. Learn what a minimal, reproducible example is.

I understood the minimal reproducible example but I'm lacking the knowledge how to do it. But finally I learn from this topic now I have submitted on the question above the reproducible example. However due to limited character, I can only manage to post 30 rows only. Sorry to keep you waiting.

I found several topic regarding filtering and grouping. I learnt from this link that filtering columns with string and numbers, if not done accordingly will result in ambiguity as the error message I post earlier. So the trick now is to find how to use groupby() syntax in order not ending up on ambiguity of the column. Any suggestion on this matter is very appreciated
